# Listing based on a particular SQL Group

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I list the names of all countries whose surface Area is greater than that of all other countries in the same region from the country Table below:

```
+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
| name                                         | region                    | surfacearea |
+----------------------------------------------+---------------------------+-------------+
| Aruba                                        | Caribbean                 |      193.00 |
| Afghanistan                                  | Southern and Central Asia |   652090.00 |
| Angola                                       | Central Africa            |  1246700.00 |
| Anguilla                                     | Caribbean                 |       96.00 |
| Albania                                      | Southern Europe           |    28748.00 |
| Andorra                                      | Southern Europe           |      468.00 |
| Netherlands Antilles                         | Caribbean                 |      800.00 |
```

So far I have come with this code but this does not list the countries ? Is this code correct ?

```
select region, max(surfacearea) as maxArea 
from country 
group by region;
```

Comment: Are you using `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?  They aren't the same thing.

Comment: No, this isn't correct.  But your question can be interpreted two different ways.  Are you looking for countries whose surface area is greater than *all other countries in the region, combined*?  Or are you looking for countries whose surface area is the largest in the region?

Comment: If you want to list the countries, you'll need to include 'name' in your SELECT statement.

Comment: @Siyual am using MySQL, am looking for countries whose surface area is the largest in the region, or greater than the (average for the region)

Comment: Including the name in the select won't work.  The max function doesn't return all the values in the row, the results are nondeterministic.    A sub-select will be required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be you can use an inner join whit a temp table

```
 select name from 
 country  as a
 inner  join      
 ( select region, max(surfacearea) as maxarea 
 from country 
 group by region ) as t    on a.region = t.region    
 where a.surfacearea =  t.maxarea;
```

Comment: I was actually posting the exact same thing, but why 'a.surfacearea > t.maxarea'?  Shoudn't the '>' be '='?

Comment: @ghenghy  you are right  .. is equal not > ... undelete you post  .. is a good answer ..

Comment: No need, we were only seconds apart, but don't want to clutter the space with essentially duplicate posts.  I assumed you just made a typo.

Comment: @ghenghy  Don't worry about a seconds  .. undelete your answer is a good answer like mine  ..and S.O. is not  only a race  ..

Comment: Thanks, but I've gotten an answer downvoted and deleted for being a duplicate in this exact scenario in the past.  I'll pass on that drama.

Comment: @ghenghy   downvote is -2 .. upvote is +10 ... then undelete .. you have done the same work that mine .. is fair .. don't worry..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the query you have identifies the "largest" value of surfacearea for each region.  To get the country, you can join the result from your query back to the country table again, to get the country that matches on region and surfacearea.

```
 SELECT c.*
   FROM ( -- largest surfacearea for each region
          SELECT n.region
               , MAX(n.surfacearea) AS max_area
            FROM country n 
           GROUP BY n.region
        ) m
   JOIN country c
     ON c.region      = m.region 
    AND c.surfacearea = m.max_area
```

Comment: ghenghy, scaisEdge and spencer7593 Two great answers. All works!!

Answer (score 1):

You can use your original query in a `WHERE IN` contition:

```sql
select *
from country
where (region, surfacearea) in (
  select region, max(surfacearea) as maxArea 
  from country 
  group by region
)
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fe544a/1)

Other ways:

```sql
select c1.*
from country c1
left join country c2
  on  c2.region = c1.region
  and c2.surfacearea > c1.surfacearea
where c2.region is null;
```

```sql
select c1.*
from country c1
where not exists (
  select *
  from country c2
  where c2.region = c1.region
    and c2.surfacearea > c1.surfacearea
);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/43ecb/6)